# how i can rigger jquery function by clicking on pre-selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can i trigger a function in jquery option if option is already selected, i want to perform ajax function through it but control is not going to the jquery function

**jquery  file:-**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#value").change(function(){
        alert("The text has been changed.");
     });
});
```

html where i want to triger a jquery function i click on selected option file:--

```
<select id="value">
    <option value="o"> SELECT-0</option>
    <option value="1" selected=selected> SELECT-1</option>
    <option value="2"> SELECT-2</option>
    <option value="3"> SELECT-3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If the option is selected when the page loads, just make the AJAX request on page load too

Comment: it works when i hit another option but i want to triger function whene someone clicks on "SELECT-1" which is pre selected is there any function alternative of this??

Comment: how can i make ajax request if i am not able to call any function??

Comment: Why can you not call any function? See prasanth's answer below to see what I meant.

Comment: i just want to say how can i perform any function when i click on the pre-selected option is there any way in jquery?

Comment: In that case please see the duplicate I have marked.

Comment: @AkshayKumar .`trigger()` function as same thing for already selected value.What you still expect . Clarify some specific of your question?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanxxxi boy help alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the change function on document.ready

**For Comment:**`when the selected option is clicked again,`. so add event of `click`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#value").on('change click',function() {
    alert("The text has been changed.");
  });
  $("#value").trigger('change')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="value">
  <option value="o"> SELECT-0</option>
  <option value="1" selected=selected> SELECT-1</option>
  <option value="2"> SELECT-2</option>
  <option value="3"> SELECT-3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just FYI it appears from the comments that the OP was asking about firing a `change` event when the selected option is clicked again, not what their question asks about firing the event on load.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i was updated

Comment: Your update doesn't let you select anything, and causes selections to occur when opening the options list.